# XSLT - Sort parents based on child node on multiple levels

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have read a lot of XSLT implementations for sorting parent nodes based on their children. But I didn't find a working solution for my case. I want to sort the ElementRef nodes according to their child node's (Element) value called 'SortField' on multiple levels. I have the following XML structure:

```
<Root>
    <OtherElement1></OtherElement1>

    <Group>
        <ID></ID>
        <Name></Name>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>B</SortField>


                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>H</SortField>


                        <ElementRef>
                        [...]
                        </ElementRef>

                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>F</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>G</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>           

            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>C</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>A</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>



    </Group>

    <OtherElement2></OtherElement2>

</Root>
```

And the result should look like:

```
<Root>
    <OtherElement1></OtherElement1>

    <Group>
        <ID></ID>
        <Name></Name>


        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>A</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>B</SortField>


                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>F</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>G</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>   

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>H</SortField>


                        <ElementRef>
                        [...]
                        </ElementRef>

                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>       

            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>C</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>


    </Group>

    <OtherElement2></OtherElement2>

</Root>
```

Can you provide me a working XSLT for that?

**Please note: It is very important that all other elements and attributes stay untouched**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template with an `xsl:sort`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[ElementRef]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="Element/SortField" data-type="text"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <OtherElement1></OtherElement1>

    <Group>
        <ID></ID>
        <Name></Name>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>B</SortField>


                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>H</SortField>


                        <ElementRef>
                            [...]
                        </ElementRef>

                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>F</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>

                <ElementRef>
                    <ID></ID>

                    <Element>
                        <ID></ID>
                        <Name></Name>
                        <SortField>G</SortField>
                    </Element>

                </ElementRef>           

            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>C</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>

        <ElementRef>
            <ID></ID>

            <Element>
                <ID></ID>
                <Name></Name>
                <SortField>A</SortField>
            </Element>

        </ElementRef>



    </Group>

    <OtherElement2></OtherElement2>

</Root>
```

into the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
   <OtherElement1/>
   <Group>
      <ID/>
      <Name/>
      <ElementRef>
         <ID/>
         <Element>
            <ID/>
            <Name/>
            <SortField>A</SortField>
         </Element>
      </ElementRef>
      <ElementRef>
         <ID/>
         <Element>
            <ID/>
            <Name/>
            <SortField>B</SortField>
            <ElementRef>
               <ID/>
               <Element>
                  <ID/>
                  <Name/>
                  <SortField>F</SortField>
               </Element>
            </ElementRef>
            <ElementRef>
               <ID/>
               <Element>
                  <ID/>
                  <Name/>
                  <SortField>G</SortField>
               </Element>
            </ElementRef>
            <ElementRef>
               <ID/>
               <Element>
                  <ID/>
                  <Name/>
                  <SortField>H</SortField>
                  <ElementRef>
                            [...]
                        </ElementRef>
               </Element>
            </ElementRef>
         </Element>
      </ElementRef>
      <ElementRef>
         <ID/>
         <Element>
            <ID/>
            <Name/>
            <SortField>C</SortField>
         </Element>
      </ElementRef>
   </Group>
   <OtherElement2/>
</Root>
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Nothing is sorted at all. I have never seen a line like this before: `<xsl:template match="*[ElementRef]">`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @user3452015, I have added the output I get for the input you posted, that output is sorted.